# Kernels Synchronisation

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm new to Cuda programming and I'm implementing the classical Floyd APSP Algorithm. This algorithm consists in 3 nested loops and all the code inside the two inner loops can be executed in parallel.

As main parts of my code, here is the kernel code:

```
__global__ void dfloyd(double *dM, size_t k, size_t n)
{
    unsigned int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    unsigned int index = y * n + x;
    double d;

    if (x < n && y < n)
    {
        d=dM[x+k*n] + dM[k+y*n];
        if (d<dM[index])
            dM[index]=d;
    }
}
```

and here is the part from the main function where the kernels are launched (for readability I omitted error handling code):

```
double *dM;
cudaMalloc((void **)&dM, sizeof_M);
cudaMemcpy(dM, hM, sizeof_M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

int dimx = 32;
int dimy = 32;
dim3 block(dimx, dimy);
dim3 grid((n + block.x - 1) / block.x, (n + block.y - 1) / block.y);

for (size_t k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    dfloyd<<<grid, block>>>(dM, k, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

cudaMemcpy(hM, dM, sizeof_M, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

[For the understanding, dM is referring to the distance matrix stored in the device side and hM in the host side and n is referring to the number of nodes.]

Kernels inside the `k`-loop have to be executed serially, this explains why I write the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` instruction after each kernel execution.
However, I notice that putting this synchro instruction **outside** the loop leads to the same result.

Now, my question. Do the two following pieces of code

```
for (size_t k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    dfloyd<<<grid, block>>>(dM, k, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

and

```
for (size_t k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    dfloyd<<<grid, block>>>(dM, k, n);
}
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent but will give the same results. The first one will make the host wait after each kernel call until the kernel has returned, while the other one will make it wait only once.
Maybe the confusing part is why does it work; in CUDA, two consecutive kernel calls on the same stream (in your case, default stream) are guaranteed to be executed serially.

Performance wise, it is advised to use the second version, as synchronisation with the host adds overhead.

Edit: in that specific case, you do not even need to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` because the `cudaMemcpy` will synchronize.

Comment: thanks for your response. The reassuring assertion I was unsure is: *two consecutive kernel calls on the same stream are guaranteed to be executed serially.*